# Cancel the modification of a TableView cell

Tags: javafx, tableview, cell, edit

I'd like to have an example which explains me how I can cancel an edit and reset the old value of a specific cell in a TableView that was edited but failed to pass through the validation. See the code below for more info.

```
tcAantalDagen.setOnEditCommit(cell -> {
        int dagen = Integer.parseInt(cell.getNewValue());
        if (Integer.parseInt(cell.getNewValue()) < 1 || Integer.parseInt(cell.getNewValue()) > 31) {
            // This shows an Alert Dialog
            Main.toonFoutbericht("Het item kan maar tussen 1 en 31 dagen uitgeleend worden");
            // The "return;" is successful in canceling the passing through of the new value of the cell to the backend code, 
            // but in the TableView the new value is still set in the cell, which can confuse the user
            return;
        }
}
```

The cell value is set like this:

```
// getAantalDagen() returns an Integer
tcAantalDagen.setCellValueFactory(cell -> {
            return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<String>(Integer.toString(cell.getValue().getAantalDagen()));
        });
// Make the cells of the tcAantalDagen column editable
tcAantalDagen.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
// The table needs to be set to editable too for the above column to work
tblUitleningen.setEditable(true);
```

Comment: What is the implementation you have for your cell?

Comment: Hey again James, my JavaFX savior! I'll edit my main post to provide you with more info.

Comment: Is my edit what you've asked?

Comment: Yes. (I'm not sure it helps me get an answer to the question though...). You may need to implement your own `TableCell` to do this (so you can validate the values before committing the edit). Why is your column a `TableColumn<?, String>` when the data appears to be an `Integer`?

Comment: Implement my own TableCell? I would have no idea how to do that. As for your next question, I had to modify the type of the cell to a string so this would work: `tcAantalDagen.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());`

Answer (score 3):

I played with this a while. The bottom line is that the default `commitEdit` method in `TableCell`, which is invoked when you commit the change in the text field in the `TextFieldTableCell`, calls `updateItem(...)` on the table cell with the new value. That's why the value in the cell is changing even though you don't change it in the model.

To prevent this, you need to implement the table cell yourself, which isn't too hard. The easiest implementation should would probably just use a text field table cell and override `updateItem(...)` to check the validity of the value. Something like

```
tcAantalDagen.setCellFactory(col -> new TextFieldTableCell<T, Integer>(new IntegerStringConverter()) {
    @Override
    public void updateItem(Integer item, boolean empty) {
        if (empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty) ;
        } else {
            // if out of range, revert to previous value:
            if (item.intValue() < 1 || item.intValue() > 31) {
                item = getItem();
            }
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
        }
    }
});
```

should work (though I haven't tested it). Obviously replace `T` with whatever the type of the items in the table are. Note that I used `Integer` as the column type here, which you can do if you provide an appropriate converter to the `TextFieldTableCell`. You would modify the cell value factory as

```
tcAantalDagen.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().aantalDagenProperty().asObject());
```

However... once you're going to all the trouble of implementing a table cell, you may as well provide one that simply doesn't allow the user to enter an invalid value, which is a much nicer user experience imho. You can do this by creating a text field for the cell that uses a [`TextFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html) that just vetoes invalid values. You have to be a little careful with these, as you want to allow values that would be partially-edited (so in general, it's not enough to allow only values that are valid, as they are checked every time the text changes, not just on commits). In this case, the only thing this means is that you should allow empty strings in the text field (else the user won't be able to delete the current value while editing, which would be awkward). You can use the converter to return the current value if the user tries to commit with an empty string.

So an implementation of this might look like

```
public class IntegerEditingCell extends TableCell<Item, Integer> {

    private TextField textField ;
    private TextFormatter<Integer> textFormatter ;

    public IntegerEditingCell(int min, int max) {
        textField = new TextField();
        UnaryOperator<TextFormatter.Change> filter = c -> {
            String newText = c.getControlNewText() ;

            // always allow deleting all characters:
            if (newText.isEmpty()) {
                return c ;
            }

            // otherwise, must have all digits:
            if (! newText.matches("\\d+")) {
                return null ;
            }

            // check range:
            int value = Integer.parseInt(newText) ;
            if (value < min || value > max) {
                return null ;
            } else {
                return c ;
            }
        };
        StringConverter<Integer> converter = new StringConverter<Integer>() {

            @Override
            public String toString(Integer value) {
                return value == null ? "" : value.toString() ;
            }

            @Override
            public Integer fromString(String string) {

                // if it's an int, return the parsed value

                if (string.matches("\\d+")) {
                    return Integer.valueOf(string);
                } else {

                    // otherwise, just return the current value of the cell:
                    return getItem() ;
                }
            }

        };
        textFormatter = new TextFormatter<Integer>(converter, 0, filter) ;
        textField.setTextFormatter(textFormatter);

        textField.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, e -> {
            if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                cancelEdit();
            }
        });

        textField.setOnAction(e -> commitEdit(converter.fromString(textField.getText())));

        textProperty().bind(Bindings
                .when(emptyProperty())
                .then((String)null)
                .otherwise(itemProperty().asString()));

        setGraphic(textField);
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Integer value, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(value, empty);
        if (isEditing()) {
            textField.requestFocus();
            textField.selectAll();
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
        } else {
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void startEdit() {
        super.startEdit();
        textFormatter.setValue(getItem());
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
        textField.requestFocus();
        textField.selectAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void commitEdit(Integer newValue) {
        super.commitEdit(newValue);
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
    }

}
```

That looks like a lot of code, but most of it is just setting up the text field and the formatter, then there's some pretty standard cell implementation that just makes sure the text field is displayed in editing mode and the plain text is displayed in non-editing mode.

Now you simply don't need to worry about checking the validity of the input, because the user cannot enter an invalid value.

Here's a simple usage example:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.function.UnaryOperator;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;

public class ValidatingTableColumn extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<Item> table = new TableView<>();
        table.setEditable(true);

        TableColumn<Item, String> nameColumn = new TableColumn<>("Item");
        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().nameProperty());

        TableColumn<Item, Integer> valueColumn = new TableColumn<>("Value");
        valueColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().valueProperty().asObject());

        table.getColumns().add(nameColumn);
        table.getColumns().add(valueColumn);

        valueColumn.setCellFactory(col -> new IntegerEditingCell(1, 31));

        valueColumn.setOnEditCommit(e -> {
            table.getItems().get(e.getTablePosition().getRow()).setValue(e.getNewValue());
        });

        Random rng = new Random();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
            table.getItems().add(new Item("Item "+i, rng.nextInt(31)+1));
        }

        Button debug = new Button("Show all values");
        debug.setOnAction(e -> table.getItems().forEach(item -> System.out.println(item.getName()+" ("+item.getValue()+")")));
        BorderPane.setAlignment(debug, Pos.CENTER);
        BorderPane.setMargin(debug, new Insets(5));

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(table, null, null, debug, null);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static class Item {
        private final IntegerProperty value = new SimpleIntegerProperty() ;
        private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();

        public Item(String name, int value) {
            setName(name);
            setValue(value);
        }

        public final IntegerProperty valueProperty() {
            return this.value;
        }

        public final int getValue() {
            return this.valueProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setValue(final int value) {
            this.valueProperty().set(value);
        }

        public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public final String getName() {
            return this.nameProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setName(final String name) {
            this.nameProperty().set(name);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: `TextFormatter` is a nice solution, but sometimes it's not applicable - for validating date or combo-box cells, for example.  In my project I find it useful to create a `ValidatingTableCell` which has a `BiPredicate` for validation (accepting the row item and the value to be committed), and a string to show as error message for the user. 

I then subclass this for text, date, combo-box etc. editing options.

Comment: Surely with a combo box or date picker it's pretty easy to enforce valid selections with the control?

Comment: Sure is, I just wanted a general solution, so I don't have to write the user-interaction part multiple times (currently I just show an alert, but later I may want to change this)

Comment: That is a working and very satisfying solution! I have a question about itthough. When I enter an empty value (so remove the old one) in the tablecell then a NullPointerException occurs at this line `if (item.intValue() < 1 || item.intValue() > 31) {`. Is there a way to circumvent this so that the old value is set again?

Comment: The custom TableCell is also very interesting for a future implementation. Thanks for that! Currently it's allowed to keep it simple as it's just a small team project for our JAVA class.

Comment: Also, what's the point of `if (empty) {
              super.updateItem(item, empty) ;
          } else {
              if (item.intValue() < 1 || item.intValue() > 31) {
                  item = getItem();
              }
              super.updateItem(item, empty);
          }` if you can just `if (item.intValue() < 1 || item.intValue() > 31) {
        item = getItem();
    }
    super.updateItem(item, empty);` ?

Comment: For the null pointer exception, I think it should work to change `if (empty)` to `if (item == null)`. The `if`-`else` structure there is specifically to avoid the null pointer exception in empty cells; but I think the `IntegerStringConverter` is providing `null` when the entry is empty.

Comment: The `if`-`else` structure is needed for empty cells (or cells where the item is null); without it you would try to call `item.intValue()` when `item` was null every time the table tried to render an empty cell.

Comment: @EarthMind and James: it's a bug that the tableCell isn't always in sync with the backing data - see https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8187314

Comment: I found the same issue, but I solved without implementing a new TableCell, just invoke TableView.refresh after reverting to the previous value so the view will be synced with model.

Comment: @bichoFlyer as I already commented to another answer - in bug hacking everything that does the job is allowed:) Nevertheless, I would tend to prefer the most "local" hack - which refresh isn't. See the bug report for an option that hacks the culprit (which is the cell)

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue like you and I found the solution. If new value is not valid, get the index of current editing row, and set data to the old object.

```
      int row = event.getTablePosition().getRow();
            ProductInOrder productInOrder = event.getTableView().getItems().get(row);
            if (newCount <0){
                Messenger.erro(bundle.getString("txt_number_must_large_or_equal_0"));
                tbProductInOrder.getItems().set(row, productInOrder);
                return;
            }
            productInOrder.setCount(newCount);
```

Comment: when [hacking around bugs](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8187314), everything is allowed :) Just for emphasis and clarifying why this is working: the data is unchanged if a custom edit commit handler doesn't accept it - it's only the cell that doesn't show the old value - so when you set the old (unchanged in every property) item in the data list, this fires a list change which in turn updates all cells of that row.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `TableView` control name is `myTableView`, then before the `return;` line, just add: `myTableView.refresh();` so, the view and model will be synced. I had the same issue and it did work for me.

```
tcAantalDagen.setOnEditCommit(cell -> {
    int dagen = Integer.parseInt(cell.getNewValue());
    if (Integer.parseInt(cell.getNewValue()) < 1 || Integer.parseInt(cell.getNewValue()) > 31) {
        // This shows an Alert Dialog
        Main.toonFoutbericht("Het item kan maar tussen 1 en 31 dagen uitgeleend worden");
         // This will resync view and model
         myTableView.refresh();
        // The "return;" is successful in canceling the passing through of the new value of the cell to the backend code
        return;
    }
});
```

Comment: the handler fails to write a valid edited value back to the data

Answer (score 0):

Calling `TableView.refresh` in a `runLater` does the trick. It forces the TableView to refresh from the model, which presumably was not changed since your logic deemed the edit "canceled".