# Problem with updating value in TableColumn Cell

Tags: java, javafx

My problem is a bit ambiguous (I don't know if it's a bug or not), i want the user to enter any value he wants, as long as it's not empty, so i created a method to check the input which returns the previous value if the input string is empty, and this is where the problem occurs, if the user clears the cell and presses the enter key, the cell displays nothing, until I click on it, here's a functional example of my project :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellEditEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Launcher extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();

        TableView<Apprenant> table = new TableView<>();
        table.setPrefWidth(800);
        table.setEditable(true);
        
        TableColumn<Apprenant, String> nom = new TableColumn<>("Noms");
        nom.setPrefWidth(100);
        
        TableColumn<Apprenant, String> prenom = new TableColumn<>("Prenoms");
        prenom.setPrefWidth(100);

        nom.setCellValueFactory(var -> var.getValue().nomProperty());
        prenom.setCellValueFactory(var -> var.getValue().prenomProperty());
        
        nom.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        nom.setOnEditCommit((CellEditEvent<Apprenant, String> evt)->{
            
            Apprenant app = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            app.setNom(check(evt.getNewValue(),app.nomProperty().get()));
    
            /*THE ONLY WAY TO DISPLAY THE UPDATED VALUE*/
            //nom.setVisible(false); 
            //nom.setVisible(true);
        });

        table.getColumns().add(nom);
        table.getColumns().add(prenom);
        table.getItems().add(new Apprenant("monNom","monPrenom"));

        root.getChildren().add(table);
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,1200,800);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    
    private static String check(String valeur,String prev)
    {
        if(valeur.isEmpty())
        {   
            return prev;
        }
        else
        {
            return valeur;
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The model :

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class Apprenant
{
    private StringProperty nom = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private StringProperty prenom = new SimpleStringProperty();
    
    public Apprenant(String nom, String prenom)
    {
        this.nom.set(nom);
        this.prenom.set(prenom);
    }
    
    public StringProperty nomProperty()
    {
        return nom;
    }
    
    public StringProperty prenomProperty()
    {
        return prenom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom)
    {
        this.nom.set(nom);
    }
    
    public void setPrenom(String prenom)
    {
        this.prenom.set(prenom);
    }

}
```

So my question is simple, how to update the cell without having to use the `setVisible` method as indicated above or the `updateItem` function ? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34698986/6722667) topic somewhat similar to mine but without any reference to my problem.

Comment: unrelated: use property naming pattern please

Comment: For example, you should have `StringProperty nomProperty()`, `String getNom()`, and `void setNom(String nom)`.

Comment: @kleopatra like that ? i'm not familiar with conventions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The editing mechanisms for virtualized controls in JavaFX are somewhat opaque...

Instead of capturing the `editCommit` event, which happens after an edit has been committed, override the `commitEdit()` method of the cell:

```
        nom.setCellFactory(tc -> new TextFieldTableCell<>(TextFormatter.IDENTITY_STRING_CONVERTER) {
            @Override
            public void commitEdit(String newValue) {
                if (newValue.isEmpty()) {
                    cancelEdit();
                } else {
                    super.commitEdit(newValue);
                }
            }
        });
//        nom.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
//        nom.setOnEditCommit((CellEditEvent<Apprenant, String> evt)->{
//            
//            Apprenant app = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
//            app.setNom(check(evt.getNewValue(),app.getNom().get()));
//    
//            /*THE ONLY WAY TO DISPLAY THE UPDATED VALUE*/
//            //nom.setVisible(false); 
//            //nom.setVisible(true);
//        });
```

This might be considered something of a hack, as it's not really the cell's job to validate data, but it's probably the path of least resistance given the API. The "correct" way to do this would probably be to perform the validation in the model, which (as far as I can see) would involve subclassing `StringPropertyBase` to support the validation.

Comment: by design, a commit handler is the way to implement accept-or-reject type of validation - concededly not overly flexible. Not showing the edited value is a bug, either in the OPs code (weird implementation to act on the selected item instead of the state passed via the event) or in fx (faintly remember some issue, too late in the day to dig)